# HTTPS redirect fails with .htaccess rewrite for certain URL length

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have an .htaccess file for showing a default image if the requested URL does not exist. I simplified it to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . default.png [L]
```

- Using **HTTPS**, this suddenly stopped working if the URL exceeds a certain length (connection closed).
- **HTTP** always works.
- It used to work like this for years and it still does on other servers.

It also seems that the kind of characters matter:

```
not working:
https://server.abc/images/01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789abc.png
https://server.abc/images/012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.png

working:
https://server.abc/images/01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.png
https://server.abc/images/01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789123.png
https://server.abc/images/0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678912345.png
```

The redirect works if the condition is removed (second line), so it seems like it has something to do with `REQUEST_FILENAME`, HTTPS and the byte size (encoding?) of the filename/URL string.

This occurs with Apache/2.4.46 and macOS/10.15.7. It might have started after one of the latest security updates.

**Any idea where this is coming from or what kind of configuration could cause this?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would start investigating by enabling rewrite logging.

Comment: Thank you very much for that tip! The log doesn't show any errors - in fact the problem is gone and everything works when I turn on rewrite logging. But it is back as soon as I turn it off...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule . default.png [L]
> ```

It's not clear why this would "fail" for only certain requests over HTTPS only. A "security" update (particularly if it involves mod_security) is a likely cause - although an unusual one.

However, you shouldn't really be doing it this way to begin with. This will result in a request for any non-existent URL being served `/default.png` with a "200 OK" response and potentially risk being indexed by search engines and abused by a malicious user.

What you are doing here is essentially setting a custom 404 response to an image, which you could do with the following instead and which will also return the "correct" 404 status.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /default.png
```

Now, any request that does not map to file (or directory) will be served the image `/default.png` but with a 404 "Not Found" HTTP response code, so search engines/bots get the "correct" response.

This also naturally gets around the `REQUEST_FILENAME` issue, assuming these "not working" URLs do ultimately result in a 404 and not some other response (due to the "security" update).

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! You are absolutely right in this case. But the actual rewrite rules are more complex. The issue is merely about the RewriteCond failing in any case.